# Equation to zero confused

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I equal to zero any equation ?
Is there any guide for this? I'm so confused about this.

Example $$ \cos(x-y)= xe^y$$

Or $$\ln\left( \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \right)= 4 - xy $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subtract one side, so change $\cos(x-y)=xe^y$ to $\cos(x-y)-xe^y=0$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes i wanted to convert the equation to zero but im confused in the way of doing it. Like $xe^y$ is in product so i have to pass e^y to the other side diving then passing x with subtract :(

Comment: You can subtract any term or combination of terms, as long as you subtract the same thing from both sides.  In this example, it doesn't matter that $xe^y$ is a product.  In your second example, we can subtract the function value that is on the left, going from $\ln (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=4-xy$  to $0=4-xy-\ln (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$